# Change Style Quasar Element

Tags: css, vue.js, select, quasar

I'm using Quasar framework for my application (https://coronavirus-statistics-app.herokuapp.com/timeline).
In the function "Timeline", I'm using q-select element for the selection of a country. I fixed the width of the q-select element but I don't succeed to fix the width of the list just below (the width is changing if the name of the country is long or not, not very user-friendly).

[image]

How to fix the width of the list below the q-select element?

My code:

```html
<q-select outlined v-model="country" :options="data" option-label="name" label="Select a Country" class="input" />

<style scoped lang="scss">
  .bg-color {
    background-color: #e7e8d1;
  }
  
  .input {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML generated for the dropdown list is separate from the input used to select it. You just need to specify a width for `q-menu`.

```
.q-menu { 
  width: 200px;
}
```

You may also apply a new class in your code so that not all the menus are 200px.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: To complete your answer; I tryed at first that solution but it didn't work. I found why: it was because of the <style scoped lang="scss"> in the page. This property was overcome by the native css of quasar.
I add .q-menu property somewhere else (in css/app.scss) to make it work.